# How can I use an array from another class?

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to use a string array populated with values from Class B in Class A.

I have tried to copy the array over as such

```
string[] playerHand2 = new string[5];
Array.Copy(Deck.playerHand, playerHand2, 5);
```

However I get a null reference exception when I try to display the contents like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Players hand:");
foreach (var item in playerHand2)
{
      Console.Write(item.ToString());
}
```

Any adive pointing me in the correct direction is much appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a simple case of `Deck.playerHand` not having the same number of items as `playerHand2` so your left with a `null` item.

Comment: Did you notice that `playerHand2` contains only nulls in the first place?

Comment: `class A` and `class B` are not shown and probably not relevant.

Comment: At what line do you get an error?

Comment: I get the error at `Console.Write(item.ToString());` It says that the Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Which I thought I did while copying over the array?

Comment: try this `Console.Write(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)?item.ToString():"");`

Comment: Deck is just public class Deck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the items in `Deck.playerHand` was already null.

This null value is copied into `playerHand2`.

When itterating through `playerHand2`, `null.ToString()` is called, resulting in your `NullReferenceException`.

You can check for a null-value with:

```
bool hasNulls = Array.IndexOf(Deck.playerHand, null) > 0;
```

or with LINQ:

```
bool hasNulls = Deck.playerHand.Any(s => s == null);
```

Comment: Okay, thank you this would mean I have an issue within the class Deck which I need to rectify

Comment: @Skittle: Correct. I updated my answer to verify if there is any NULL in your collection.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works perfectly fine for me:

```
    string[] playerHand = new string[7] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
    string[] playerHand2 = new string[5];
    Array.Copy(playerHand, playerHand2, 5);

    Console.WriteLine("Players hand:");
    foreach (var item in playerHand2)
    {
        Console.Write(item.ToString());
    }
```

Did you actually fill your array 'playerHand' with valid data?
Else make sure you have no null-values in the array of 'playerHand', and the size of 'playerHand' must be at least as big as 'playerHand2'.

Else you can simply avoid this

```
 foreach (var item in playerHand2)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) { continue; }
            Console.Write(item.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: It would appear within class Deck, where I contain an original array that is then shuffled and split, I have done something wrong and there not filling playerHand. Thank you nice to know where my problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to copy the Array to use it, and converting a string to string is not helpful.

You can simply use:

```
foreach (var item in Deck.playerHand)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

in general, you can also overwrite `null` with " " using the following:

```
for(int x = 0; x < Deck.playerHand.Length; x++)
{
   if(Deck.playerHand[x] == null)
   {
      Deck.playerHand[x] = " ";
   }
}
```

combined that gives following code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < Deck.playerHand.Length; x++)
{
   if(Deck.playerHand[x] == null)
   {
      Deck.playerHand[x] = " ";
   }
   Console.WriteLine(Deck.playerHand[x]);
}
```

or even more compact, see @saravanan:

```
foreach(string item in Deck.playerHand)
{
   Console.Write(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)?item.ToString():"");
}
```